# Enforce Json schema validation, on rest endpoint, to verify the integrity of Json response

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, microservices, jsonschema

Working on developing rest endpoint, with spring-boot, to consume a resource from another microservice (external), since both the services are in development phases, there is quite a lot of changes in request and response frequently. Many times our micro-service failed because of change in response from the target microservice.

To avoid this failure, we thought of Defining a JSON schema in the calling client to describe the expected response.

If there is a schema mismatch log an error message, prefixed with "JSON_SCHEMA_MISMATCH".

Please advise if there are any other better solutions for handling this in a more generic way, meaning the same could be used for other microservices as well without more duplicated codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use objects to directly fetch the values from the services.
For example -
    VOClass vOobject = restTemplate.getForObject(url, VOClass.class, params);

The microservice which you are using should also return the same object, or the json with same variable names.
If there are variables you are getting in response match the variables from your VOClass object then those values will be set and those not matching will be null.
ALso if there are new varaibles returned from microservice, you can cosume them by adding those variables in your VOClass.